# Modelling partial enumeration

Tags: java, oop, enums, software-design

Let's say I have a field called `Specifier` which can be one of 100 instances (this number can increase in the future). In the code I'm generally using only subset of those for comparison and logic.

What would be the best way to model this kind of behavior?

```
Specifier s = new Specifier(123);
Specifier s2 = Specifier.KNOWN; //KNOWN == Specifier(123)

//possible comparation should be true since KNOWN can be 123
(s == s2) == true;
```

In this case it seems like I could model `Specifier` as `enum`, but the problem then is that I cannot init `new Specifier()`.

I could also express all of 100 enums in code, but if only one change in the DB, I need to update my code and recompile...

I could have KNOWN as `public static final` fields inside Specifier - which is one option, but not sure is this inferior to `enum` approach?

I could have `enum` implementing an interface, but this seems too clumsy.

Any other thoughts on this one?

Comment: What is your aim here. Is it to have a class that you can compare using `==`, or something else?

Comment: Also, do you *need* to be able to get hold of an instance using `new`? If so, why?

Comment: yes. lets say i deserialize message where Specifier can be any of 100 ceses. Then i compare it and only if equal to Specifier.KNOWN do some logic. otherwise i just re-serialize and forward.

Comment: Is it right that the main point is to be able to compare with `==`, and let it have the same "semantics" as a comparison with `equals`?

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's much argument for using anything other than a regular class with a properly implemented `.equals` method. As you said, `KNOWN` can be a `static final` variable. Make sure you check for equality using `KNOWN.equals(other)` rather than `KNOWN == other`. Any solution using enums, or anything more sophisticated, will involve you jumping through hoops to get it working (e.g. to get round no `new`), and by the sounds of things you don't have any requirements beyond construction and equality checking.

Comment: The main use of an enum would be to restrict the set of possible values (e.g. to check that a deserialised value is 'valid), or to obtain an exhaustive list of all poissble value. However, it doesn't sound like you want to do this.

Comment: I updated the question... seems like that is the best option. I also added flyweight so I can compare with "=="

Comment: @BojanVukasovic Why would you need the new operator? Can't you just get it from a static method like `Specifier.of` (i.e. are all specifier values known at compile time)?

Comment: @Avi no. it's dynamic.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic It's probably best to go with your flyweight approach then.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic *Why* do you want to use `==` so badly?

Comment: @MCEmperor That is not requirement - just nice to have if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this implementation with flyweight looks the best (since I can also use `==` instead of `equals`)

```
public class Specifier {
  private static final Map<String, Specifier> flyweights = new HashMap<>();

  public static final Specifier KNOWN1 = Specifier.of("1");
  public static final Specifier KNOWN2 = Specifier.of("2");
  public static final Specifier KNOWN3 = Specifier.of("3");

  static {
        flyweights.put(KNOWN1.value(), KNOWN1);
        flyweights.put(KNOWN2.value(), KNOWN2);
        flyweights.put(KNOWN3.value(), KNOWN3);
  }

  private final String value;

  public static Specifier of(String value) {
    return flyweights.computeIfAbsent(value, v -> new Specifier(value));
  }
}
```